# MUI Drawer with react-router-dom do not activate the transition effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I wanted to combine the persistent drawer like the [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/) in the MUI website with the react-router-dom. The only problem I found is that the transition effect doesn't works anymore, the paragraph does not resize to make room for the opening drawer, and therefore the latter ends up overlapping the text.
I've setup a [working Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-euler-k6lw22?file=/Drawer.js)

The open prop passed to the route page seems not activating the transition here:

```js
const Main = styled(MScreen, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
    ...(open && {
      transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      }),
      marginLeft: 0
    })
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style an actual DOM element.

You can do this by passing the `className` prop through to the `div` element:

Main.js

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const MScreen = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}> // <-- className prop passed through
      <CssBaseline />
      <Typography paragraph>
        ....
      </Typography>
      <Typography paragraph>
        ....
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};

const Main = styled(MScreen, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
    ...(open && {
      marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      }),
    })
  })
);
export default Main;
```

[image: Edit mui-drawer-with-react-router-dom-do-not-activate-the-transition-effect(1)]

Or by refactoring to rendered a styled `main` element directly:

Main.js

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

const drawerWidth = 240;

// Style a "main" HTML element
const Main = styled("main", { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
    ...(open && {
      marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      }),
    })
  })
);

const MScreen = ({ open }) => {
  return (
    <Main open={open}> // <-- pass open prop through to Main component
      <CssBaseline />
      <Typography paragraph>
        ....
      </Typography>
      <Typography paragraph>
        ...
      </Typography>
    </Main>
  );
};

export default MScreen; // <-- export MScreen content component
```

[image: Edit mui-drawer-with-react-router-dom-do-not-activate-the-transition-effect]

[image]

[image]

You'll need to apply similar fix to `Second` component as well for it to render correctly. I'd recommend creating a layout route for the "main content" area that renders an `Outlet` for routes render their content into so you only need to handle the drawer styling in one routed component instead of all of them.